# Get all active records WHERE param array contains a specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails controller I'd like to retrieve only the Projects where the current user's id is in a param array.

This is what I currently have:

```
class MyProjectsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @projects = Project.where(team_member: [@user])
  end

  private

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :team_member => [])
  end

end
```

My expectation was that this would return projects if @user was **included** in the array...

It actually only returns projects if @user is the only value in the array. If the array contains multiple values nothing is returned.

I'm fairly new to rails and feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
So I was adding Users to a Project via a column on the Projects table called :team_member which accepts an array of user IDs.

I did get this to work by doing a query like this:

```
@projects = Project.where(":team_member = ANY(team_member)", team_member: 
[current_user.id])
```

This returns only projects where current_user.id exists in the :team_member array.

BUT I realize that I really need to perhaps do this with a join table on User and Projects and add users to projects that way. Thanks for the comments...they all helped me think through this.

Comment: try `.where('team_member IN (?)', [@user.id, 3,4,5])`

Comment: Is the `team_member` attribute on `Project` and `array`? If so, you're fundamentally going after this is the wrong way. You should be using associations. That's what they're for.

Comment: Your reply got me on the right track. I am using postgres and attached users to a project via a :team_member column which accepts an array of user IDs. I realize now that I need a different approach to attach multiple users to a project. I'm going create an association...thanks!

Comment: worth mentioning that I did get my current query to work with this...@projects = Project.where(":team_member = ANY(team_member)", team_member: [current_user])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could help better you show us the Project model. Specifically the association between Project and team_member.

If team_member is a has_many association, you could join it and filter by their ids, like:

```
Project.joins(:team_members).where(team_members: { id: YOUR_ARRAY_OF_IDS })
```

But maybe team_member is an array, or some sort of data serialized in Project model, for that we could search array elements using ANY or ALL, using postgresql, I can't tell much about other DBMS.

Please tell more about this model and it's associations

Comment: Yes team_member is an array on the project model. Your answer pushed me in the right direction. See my update above...I was able to make the query work with an ANY postgres query, but I am re-working the user/project relationship so that it has an association. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use either has_any_belongs_to_many relationship , or has_many :through for essay querying database

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
@projects = Project.all.where(team_member: current_user)
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah I thought team_member was a column in the projects table.